# How do I select a bunch of elements in a css class separately from other elements?

Tags: css

My question can be very complex, because I don't know either what I am talking about, I am literally a newbie at coding.

So, a have a header mega menu, but the titles in it don't hover when the mouse is over. I want them to be hovered, but their CSS class is "menu-item" and when I apply the hover css on this, every menu on my theme gets hovered.

What should be my solution? The element ID's in my mega menu starting with 50xxx like "menu-title-5082" or "menu-title-5083" and the other menu titles, like main menu, are starting with another numbers. So I thought it would be a solution, when I select all elements starting with 50xx. But how can I do that, or would it be a solution? Thanks!

My code was:

```
    .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

and it didn't work properly because all menu items affected, so I tried this:

```
    .menu-item-50:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

and it didn't work at all.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Can you try the last one? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors `[class~="menu-item-50"]`

Comment: CSS doesn't wildcard select, the reason `.menu-item` worked is because all your menu items have `class="menu-item menu-item-xxxxx"`

Comment: you probably just need to wrap the bit you want the background on in a separate element rather than putting the hover on the whole element and it's siblings

Comment: @Pete how can I do that? could you give me an example? The element I try to put a background is "fusion-header-title".

Comment: @m4n0 I am adding these codes to my theme's "extra css" section, how can I add this one? All codes are like

.css {
}
Should I write it like this:

[class~="menu-item-50"]:hover {
}
I tried something like that and didn't worked. How can I apply this? Seems rational, I looked at the mozilla page. Could be useful but the application part I couldn't success.

Comment: You need to edit your question and use the snippet button so we can see your html too - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Pete okay, I will do that